# command php artisan optimize not defined in Lumen 5

Tags: laravel, lumen

I am using Lumen 5.1.6 , Is there any way to improve its performance? my API is taking long time (around 9000 ms) to response.I searched and found `php artisan optimize` and `php artisan route:cache` commands but these are not available in Lumen. Can anybody please help me to reduce API response time ? Thanks much!!!

Comment: If your app takes more than 9 seconds to load, you need to find an other solution than these commands. Either it's your server that is not configured properly, or it is your code that is doing something wrong. Are you making a lot of sql calls?

Comment: @El_Matella , yes it has lot of functions calling many sql , but the same functions and queries are working fast (around 3000 ms) in Codeigniter.